# Increase buffer duration of video of my local Chrome installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, streaming

In my region, youtube is fast, so seeking is rarely an issue there. But some sites are a bit slow so seeking can be annoying.

In that case, I would prefer to buffer at least the next 2-5 minutes in advance. Is it possible to increase the setting somehow for my local Chrome installation?

Comment: [Buffer First, Watch Video Later - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buffer-first-watch-video/nfmmfalangpoddnbmpggkogocecengab)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's for YouTube. I have no issues on youtube